# Pagination in UITableview in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a tableview in my application, into which I am loading different types of cells. I need to pass the page number to the service as one, two, etc. and to load that when the 1st page ends. For the first one I am loading the count is 10, after that when scroll ends I need to load the next. I am using Rest client Webservices. 
This is my json webservices.

```
{
    "userId":2,
    "encryptPassword":"50ec0d1b0559dbba51a58bed38aabf7bc6066641",
    "pagination":{
        "lastId":0,
        "resultsPerPage":10
    },
    "status_id":1,
    "request_type_id":2,
    "isAgent":false,
    "searchKey":""
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have some good ideas, now just implement them buddy.

Comment: What seems to be the problem ?

Comment: @n00bProgrammer thanks for your response.I have no idea of how to using pagination to the uitableview using webservices....

Answer (score 4):

Ok lets say you are pinging server for first 10 data and showing it into `tableview` now what you have to do.

- Take a global `int` variable like `int lastLoadedId=0;`
- When you parse your data simply store the last loaded id in `lastLoadedId` variable to track now where you are.
- implement the `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView` delegate method to know that you are at the bottom and you need new next data set.

-

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
    {
        // you are in the end ping server with lastLoadedId for new data
    }
}
```

-

- After getting new data set simply append them at the bottom of your `tableview`

Comment: thanks for your response.But i had small doubt.after parsing how to store the last loaded id.please clarify my doubt or any sample code.

Comment: last loaded id means you have keep track that how much data is loaded into table view from server.

Comment: @Tatpas pal thanks for your response.in response am getting request_id for each row which i have to pass as lastloadedid.how to get the requestid for last row in tableview...

Comment: you must use an array. So simply pick the lastObject and get the last id.

Comment: @Tatpas Pal thanks for your response.But i had small doubt.How to get the lastOject ?please helpme..

Answer (score 0):

The UITableView does not really have a concept of "pagination". It does have sections you might use. For example you could specify 10 sections with 10 cells (or rows) each.  Each section can have a different number of cells.

Each section can have a header or a footer or both.  You could put your page number into the footer of each section.

Comment: thanks for your response.But i have no idea this concept  how to make this functionality.please give me any sample code or tutorial based on my above webservices...